# Сервер МС не отвечает, curlErrorNumber: 52

Tags: мойсклад-api, moysklad-json-api

Есть проблема с АПИ, на запрос скрипта через curl сервер МС не отвечает, вот пример: https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/entity/product?filter=externalCode=3828;
При этом в браузере он открывается,на тестовом сервере все работает и другие запросы на этом тоже работают

```
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);

    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $msk_login.":".$msk_password);
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.2309.372 Safari/537.36');
```

Answer (score -1):

Ответ:
curl_init()
--//--
curl_close
перед каждым вызовом АПИ